# I need to check whether adding value already exists in Map and add values to list of integers in Map

Tags: java, list, dictionary, tokenize

I need to create a Map with string as a key and list of integers as a value. I have created the Map, I created tokenization of words which I get from txt file. Right now I am trying to put keys and values into map, but I am still receving errors. I am wondering that maybe my Map has been created wrong, but I don't see any other way to create this map.

I've been trying to add this map with "put" function, in this way I cannot even compile this program

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
        //Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();    
        int numberOfFiles;
        File directory = new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/documents java project/");
        numberOfFiles = directory.list().length;


        for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfFiles; i++) {
            //tokenization of string
            String filePath = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/documents java project/document "+ i +".txt";
            String fileData = readFile(filePath);
            String delimiter = " ";
            String fileWords [] = fileData.split(delimiter);
            //words.add(fileWords);
            int numberOfWords = fileWords.length;

            for(int j = 0; j < numberOfWords; j++) {

                map.put(fileWords[j], i);

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The map is `Map<String, List<Integer>>` but you're trying to put single integers as values with `map.put(fileWords[j], i)`. What do you intend to store in the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Map` is expecting the value to be a `List<Integer>` but you are trying to put an `int` into it instead:

```
map.put(fileWords[j], i);
```

Instead, you need to create a `List<Integer>` and put that as the value, like:

```
if (!map.containsKey(fileWords[j])) {
    map.put(fileWords[j], new ArrayList<>());
}
map.get(fileWords[j]).add(i);
```

This will add a new empty `List` to your `Map` if it doesn't already exist, and then it will add the value of `i` to the list. If it does already exist, it will just add `i` to the list that is already there.

This can also be done with [`Map.computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) if the above is too wordy for your tastes:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(fileWords[j], k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
```

If you don't want to store duplicates, you can use a `Set` instead. Change your declaration to:

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

And later, to add items:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(fileWords[j], k -> new HashSet<>()).add(i);
```

Comment: Great, thank you for your quick answer and for your help.

Comment: Maybe one more thing. Right now everything is working great, but for example for some key I have a value which is reapeted like {word = [1,1,2,2], because this word exists in first and second document twice. How can I get rid of doubled values?